# Memory consumption increased after porting from MatLab to NumPy - how can I compensate?

Tags: numpy, matlab, memory

When calibrating magnetometers, I quickly get arrays with 40k+ rows, even after cutting out data without movement/information. With Matlab, that works, while my NumpY code exits because of memory constraints. How can I reduce the memory footprint? I am okay with a little longer execution time. The Data comes in with a resolution of 24bit, while the NumPy array is in double precision (I think?). In practice, I struggle with accuracy, so I would prefer not to sacrifice on that end.

```
[x,y,z] = ellipsoid(0,-0.5,0,6,3.25,3.25);
A=[x(:),y(:),z(:)];
[U, c] = MgnCalibration(A)

function [U,c] = MgnCalibration(X)
% performs magnetometer calibration from a set of data
% using Merayo technique with a non iterative algoritm
% J.Merayo et al. "Scalar calibration of vector magnemoters"
% Meas. Sci. Technol. 11 (2000) 120-132.
%
%   X      : a Nx3 (or 3xN) data matrix
%              each row (columns) contains x, y, z measurements
%              N must be such that the data set describes
%              as completely as possible the 3D space
%              In any case N > 10
%              
%    The calibration tries to find the best 3D ellipsoid that fits the data set
%    and returns the parameters of this ellipsoid
%
%    U     :  shape ellipsoid parameter, (3x3) upper triangular matrix
%    c      : ellipsoid center, (3x1) vector
%
%    Ellipsoid equation : (v-c)'*(U'*U)(v-c) = 1 
%    with v a rough triaxes magnetometer  measurement
%
%    calibrated measurement w = U*(v-c)
%
%   author : Alain Barraud, Suzanne Lesecq 2008
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[N,m] = size(X);
if m>3&&N==3,X = X';N = m;m = 3;end;%check that X is not transposed
if N<=10,U = [];c = [];return;end;%not enough data no calibration !!
% write  the ellipsoid equation as D*p=0
% the best parameter is the solution of min||D*p|| with ||p||=1;
% form D matrix from X measurements
x = X(:,1); y = X(:,2); z = X(:,3); 
D = [x.^2, y.^2, z.^2, x.*y, x.*z, y.*z, x, y, z, ones(N,1)]
D=triu(qr(D)) %avoids to compute the svd of a large matrix
[U,S,V] = svd(D);%because usually N may be very large
p = V(:,end);if p(1)<0,p =-p;end;
% the following matrix A(p) must be positive definite
% The optimization done by svd does not include such a constraint
% With "good" data the constraint is allways satisfied
% With too poor data A may fail to be positive definite
% In this case the calibration fails
%
A = [p(1) p(4)/2 p(5)/2;
       p(4)/2 p(2) p(6)/2; 
       p(5)/2 p(6)/2 p(3)];
[U,ok] = fchol(m,A);
if ~ok,U = [];c = [];return;end%calibration fails too poor data!!
b = [p(7);p(8);p(9)];
v = Utsolve(U,b/2,m);
d = p(10);
s = 1/sqrt(v*v'-d);
c =-Usolve(U,v,m)';%ellipsoid center
U = s*U;%shape ellipsoid parameter
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function [A,ok] = fchol(n,A)
% performs Cholesky factoristation
A(1,1:n) = A(1,1:n)/sqrt(A(1,1));
A(2:n,1) = 0;
for j=2:n
  A(j,j:n) = A(j,j:n) - A(1:j-1,j)'*A(1:j-1,j:n);
  if A(j,j)<=0,ok=0;break;end%A is not positive definite
  A(j,j:n) = A(j,j:n)/sqrt(A(j,j));
  A(j+1:n,j) = 0;
end
ok=1;
end
function x=Utsolve(U,b,n)
% solves U'*x=b
x(1) = b(1)/U(1,1);
for k=2:n
    x(k) = (b(k)-x(1:k-1)*U(1:k-1,k))/U(k,k);
end
end
function x=Usolve(U,b,n)
% solves U*x=b
x(n) = b(n)/U(n,n);
for k=n-1:-1:1
    x(k) = (b(k)-U(k,k+1:n)*x(k+1:n)')/U(k,k);
end
end
```

That was the Matlab code, and here is the equivalent NumPy code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import qr, svd


def calibrate_magnetometer(calibration_data: np.ndarray):
    """
     performs magnetometer calibration from a set of data
     using Merayo technique with a non iterative algoritm
     J.Merayo et al. "Scalar calibration of vector magnemoters"
     Meas. Sci. Technol. 11 (2000) 120-132.

       X      : a Nx3 (or 3xN) data matrix
                  each row (columns) contains x, y, z measurements
                  N must be such that the data set describes
                     as completely as possible the 3D space
                  In any case N > 10

        The calibration tries to find the best 3D ellipsoid that fits the data set
        and returns the parameters of this ellipsoid

        U     :  shape ellipsoid parameter, (3x3) upper triangular matrix
        c      : ellipsoid center, (3x1) vector

        Ellipsoid equation : (v-c)'*(U'*U)(v-c) = 1
        with v a rough triaxes magnetometer  measurement

        calibrated measurement w = U*(v-c)

       author : Alain Barraud, Suzanne Lesecq 2008
    """
    (n, m) = calibration_data.shape
    if m > 3 and n == 3:  # check that x is not transposed
        calibration_data = calibration_data.T
        n = m
        m = 3
    if n <= 10:
        return False  # not enough data for calibration

    # write the ellipsoid equation as D*p=0
    # the best parameter is the solution of min||D*p|| with ||p||=1
    # form D matix from X measurements
    x = calibration_data[:, 0]
    y = calibration_data[:, 1]
    z = calibration_data[:, 2]

    D = [np.square(x), np.square(y), np.square(z),
         np.multiply(x,y), np.multiply(x,z), np.multiply(y,z),
         x, y, z,
         np.ones(n)]
    D = np.array(D)

    D = np.triu(qr(D.T)[1])  # avoids to compute the svd of a large matrix
    u, s, v = svd(D)  # because usually N may be very large
    p = v[-1]
    if p[0] < 0:
        p = -p
    # the following matrix a(p) must be positive definite.
    # the optimization done by svd does not include such a constrain
    # with "good" data the constrain is allways satisfied
    # with too poor data A may fail to be positive definite
    # in this case the calibration fails

    a = np.array([[p[0], p[3] / 2, p[4] / 2],
                  [p[3] / 2, p[1], p[5] / 2],
                  [p[4] / 2, p[5] / 2, p[2]]])
    uu = np.linalg.cholesky(a)
    b = np.array([p[6], p[7], p[8]])
    vv = utsolve(uu, b / 2, m)
    d = p[9]
    s = 1 / np.sqrt(vv * vv.T - d)
    calibrated_c = -usolve(uu, vv, m)  # ellipsoid center, or offset error
    calibrated_u = s * uu  # shape ellipsoid parameter
    return calibrated_u, calibrated_c


def utsolve(u, b, n):
    # solves u.T*x=b
    x = np.zeros(n)

    x[0] = b[0] / u[0, 0]
    for k in range(1, n):
        x[k] = (b[k] - np.matmul(x[0:k], u[0:k, k])) / u[k, k]
    return x


def usolve(u, b, n):
    # solves u*x=b
    x = np.zeros((n, 1))

    x[n - 1] = b[n - 1] / u[n - 1, n - 1]
    for k in reversed(range(0, n - 1)):
        x[k] = (b[k] - np.matmul(u[k, k + 1:n], x[k + 1:n].T[0])) / u[k, k]
    return x.T[0]


def main():
    a = np.array([[0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [-0.9386, -0.5000, -3.2100],
                  [-1.8541, -0.5000, -3.0909],
                  [-2.7239, -0.5000, -2.8958],
                  [-3.5267, -0.5000, -2.6293],
                  [-4.2426, -0.5000, -2.2981],
                  [-4.8541, -0.5000, -1.9103],
                  [-5.3460, -0.5000, -1.4755],
                  [-5.7063, -0.5000, -1.0043],
                  [-5.9261, -0.5000, -0.5084],
                  [-6.0000, -0.5000, 0],
                  [-5.9261, -0.5000, 0.5084],
                  [-5.7063, -0.5000, 1.0043],
                  [-5.3460, -0.5000, 1.4755],
                  [-4.8541, -0.5000, 1.9103],
                  [-4.2426, -0.5000, 2.2981],
                  [-3.5267, -0.5000, 2.6293],
                  [-2.7239, -0.5000, 2.8958],
                  [-1.8541, -0.5000, 3.0909],
                  [-0.9386, -0.5000, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [-0.8927, -0.6571, -3.2100],
                  [-1.7634, -0.8103, -3.0909],
                  [-2.5906, -0.9559, -2.8958],
                  [-3.3541, -1.0903, -2.6293],
                  [-4.0350, -1.2102, -2.2981],
                  [-4.6165, -1.3125, -1.9103],
                  [-5.0844, -1.3948, -1.4755],
                  [-5.4271, -1.4552, -1.0043],
                  [-5.6361, -1.4919, -0.5084],
                  [-5.7063, -1.5043, 0],
                  [-5.6361, -1.4919, 0.5084],
                  [-5.4271, -1.4552, 1.0043],
                  [-5.0844, -1.3948, 1.4755],
                  [-4.6165, -1.3125, 1.9103],
                  [-4.0350, -1.2102, 2.2981],
                  [-3.3541, -1.0903, 2.6293],
                  [-2.5906, -0.9559, 2.8958],
                  [-1.7634, -0.8103, 3.0909],
                  [-0.8927, -0.6571, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [-0.7593, -0.7988, -3.2100],
                  [-1.5000, -1.0903, -3.0909],
                  [-2.2037, -1.3673, -2.8958],
                  [-2.8532, -1.6228, -2.6293],
                  [-3.4324, -1.8508, -2.2981],
                  [-3.9271, -2.0455, -1.9103],
                  [-4.3250, -2.2021, -1.4755],
                  [-4.6165, -2.3168, -1.0043],
                  [-4.7943, -2.3868, -0.5084],
                  [-4.8541, -2.4103, 0],
                  [-4.7943, -2.3868, 0.5084],
                  [-4.6165, -2.3168, 1.0043],
                  [-4.3250, -2.2021, 1.4755],
                  [-3.9271, -2.0455, 1.9103],
                  [-3.4324, -1.8508, 2.2981],
                  [-2.8532, -1.6228, 2.6293],
                  [-2.2037, -1.3673, 2.8958],
                  [-1.5000, -1.0903, 3.0909],
                  [-0.7593, -0.7988, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [-0.5517, -0.9113, -3.2100],
                  [-1.0898, -1.3125, -3.0909],
                  [-1.6011, -1.6937, -2.8958],
                  [-2.0729, -2.0455, -2.6293],
                  [-2.4938, -2.3592, -2.2981],
                  [-2.8532, -2.6272, -1.9103],
                  [-3.1423, -2.8427, -1.4755],
                  [-3.3541, -3.0006, -1.0043],
                  [-3.4833, -3.0969, -0.5084],
                  [-3.5267, -3.1293, 0],
                  [-3.4833, -3.0969, 0.5084],
                  [-3.3541, -3.0006, 1.0043],
                  [-3.1423, -2.8427, 1.4755],
                  [-2.8532, -2.6272, 1.9103],
                  [-2.4938, -2.3592, 2.2981],
                  [-2.0729, -2.0455, 2.6293],
                  [-1.6011, -1.6937, 2.8958],
                  [-1.0898, -1.3125, 3.0909],
                  [-0.5517, -0.9113, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [-0.2900, -0.9835, -3.2100],
                  [-0.5729, -1.4552, -3.0909],
                  [-0.8417, -1.9033, -2.8958],
                  [-1.0898, -2.3168, -2.6293],
                  [-1.3110, -2.6856, -2.2981],
                  [-1.5000, -3.0006, -1.9103],
                  [-1.6520, -3.2540, -1.4755],
                  [-1.7634, -3.4397, -1.0043],
                  [-1.8313, -3.5529, -0.5084],
                  [-1.8541, -3.5909, 0],
                  [-1.8313, -3.5529, 0.5084],
                  [-1.7634, -3.4397, 1.0043],
                  [-1.6520, -3.2540, 1.4755],
                  [-1.5000, -3.0006, 1.9103],
                  [-1.3110, -2.6856, 2.2981],
                  [-1.0898, -2.3168, 2.6293],
                  [-0.8417, -1.9033, 2.8958],
                  [-0.5729, -1.4552, 3.0909],
                  [-0.2900, -0.9835, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.0000, -1.0084, -3.2100],
                  [0.0000, -1.5043, -3.0909],
                  [0.0000, -1.9755, -2.8958],
                  [0.0000, -2.4103, -2.6293],
                  [0.0000, -2.7981, -2.2981],
                  [0.0000, -3.1293, -1.9103],
                  [0.0000, -3.3958, -1.4755],
                  [0.0000, -3.5909, -1.0043],
                  [0.0000, -3.7100, -0.5084],
                  [0.0000, -3.7500, 0],
                  [0.0000, -3.7100, 0.5084],
                  [0.0000, -3.5909, 1.0043],
                  [0.0000, -3.3958, 1.4755],
                  [0.0000, -3.1293, 1.9103],
                  [0.0000, -2.7981, 2.2981],
                  [0.0000, -2.4103, 2.6293],
                  [0.0000, -1.9755, 2.8958],
                  [0.0000, -1.5043, 3.0909],
                  [0.0000, -1.0084, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.2900, -0.9835, -3.2100],
                  [0.5729, -1.4552, -3.0909],
                  [0.8417, -1.9033, -2.8958],
                  [1.0898, -2.3168, -2.6293],
                  [1.3110, -2.6856, -2.2981],
                  [1.5000, -3.0006, -1.9103],
                  [1.6520, -3.2540, -1.4755],
                  [1.7634, -3.4397, -1.0043],
                  [1.8313, -3.5529, -0.5084],
                  [1.8541, -3.5909, 0],
                  [1.8313, -3.5529, 0.5084],
                  [1.7634, -3.4397, 1.0043],
                  [1.6520, -3.2540, 1.4755],
                  [1.5000, -3.0006, 1.9103],
                  [1.3110, -2.6856, 2.2981],
                  [1.0898, -2.3168, 2.6293],
                  [0.8417, -1.9033, 2.8958],
                  [0.5729, -1.4552, 3.0909],
                  [0.2900, -0.9835, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.5517, -0.9113, -3.2100],
                  [1.0898, -1.3125, -3.0909],
                  [1.6011, -1.6937, -2.8958],
                  [2.0729, -2.0455, -2.6293],
                  [2.4938, -2.3592, -2.2981],
                  [2.8532, -2.6272, -1.9103],
                  [3.1423, -2.8427, -1.4755],
                  [3.3541, -3.0006, -1.0043],
                  [3.4833, -3.0969, -0.5084],
                  [3.5267, -3.1293, 0],
                  [3.4833, -3.0969, 0.5084],
                  [3.3541, -3.0006, 1.0043],
                  [3.1423, -2.8427, 1.4755],
                  [2.8532, -2.6272, 1.9103],
                  [2.4938, -2.3592, 2.2981],
                  [2.0729, -2.0455, 2.6293],
                  [1.6011, -1.6937, 2.8958],
                  [1.0898, -1.3125, 3.0909],
                  [0.5517, -0.9113, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.7593, -0.7988, -3.2100],
                  [1.5000, -1.0903, -3.0909],
                  [2.2037, -1.3673, -2.8958],
                  [2.8532, -1.6228, -2.6293],
                  [3.4324, -1.8508, -2.2981],
                  [3.9271, -2.0455, -1.9103],
                  [4.3250, -2.2021, -1.4755],
                  [4.6165, -2.3168, -1.0043],
                  [4.7943, -2.3868, -0.5084],
                  [4.8541, -2.4103, 0],
                  [4.7943, -2.3868, 0.5084],
                  [4.6165, -2.3168, 1.0043],
                  [4.3250, -2.2021, 1.4755],
                  [3.9271, -2.0455, 1.9103],
                  [3.4324, -1.8508, 2.2981],
                  [2.8532, -1.6228, 2.6293],
                  [2.2037, -1.3673, 2.8958],
                  [1.5000, -1.0903, 3.0909],
                  [0.7593, -0.7988, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.8927, -0.6571, -3.2100],
                  [1.7634, -0.8103, -3.0909],
                  [2.5906, -0.9559, -2.8958],
                  [3.3541, -1.0903, -2.6293],
                  [4.0350, -1.2102, -2.2981],
                  [4.6165, -1.3125, -1.9103],
                  [5.0844, -1.3948, -1.4755],
                  [5.4271, -1.4552, -1.0043],
                  [5.6361, -1.4919, -0.5084],
                  [5.7063, -1.5043, 0],
                  [5.6361, -1.4919, 0.5084],
                  [5.4271, -1.4552, 1.0043],
                  [5.0844, -1.3948, 1.4755],
                  [4.6165, -1.3125, 1.9103],
                  [4.0350, -1.2102, 2.2981],
                  [3.3541, -1.0903, 2.6293],
                  [2.5906, -0.9559, 2.8958],
                  [1.7634, -0.8103, 3.0909],
                  [0.8927, -0.6571, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.9386, -0.5000, -3.2100],
                  [1.8541, -0.5000, -3.0909],
                  [2.7239, -0.5000, -2.8958],
                  [3.5267, -0.5000, -2.6293],
                  [4.2426, -0.5000, -2.2981],
                  [4.8541, -0.5000, -1.9103],
                  [5.3460, -0.5000, -1.4755],
                  [5.7063, -0.5000, -1.0043],
                  [5.9261, -0.5000, -0.5084],
                  [6.0000, -0.5000, 0],
                  [5.9261, -0.5000, 0.5084],
                  [5.7063, -0.5000, 1.0043],
                  [5.3460, -0.5000, 1.4755],
                  [4.8541, -0.5000, 1.9103],
                  [4.2426, -0.5000, 2.2981],
                  [3.5267, -0.5000, 2.6293],
                  [2.7239, -0.5000, 2.8958],
                  [1.8541, -0.5000, 3.0909],
                  [0.9386, -0.5000, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.8927, -0.3429, -3.2100],
                  [1.7634, -0.1897, -3.0909],
                  [2.5906, -0.0441, -2.8958],
                  [3.3541, 0.0903, -2.6293],
                  [4.0350, 0.2102, -2.2981],
                  [4.6165, 0.3125, -1.9103],
                  [5.0844, 0.3948, -1.4755],
                  [5.4271, 0.4552, -1.0043],
                  [5.6361, 0.4919, -0.5084],
                  [5.7063, 0.5043, 0],
                  [5.6361, 0.4919, 0.5084],
                  [5.4271, 0.4552, 1.0043],
                  [5.0844, 0.3948, 1.4755],
                  [4.6165, 0.3125, 1.9103],
                  [4.0350, 0.2102, 2.2981],
                  [3.3541, 0.0903, 2.6293],
                  [2.5906, -0.0441, 2.8958],
                  [1.7634, -0.1897, 3.0909],
                  [0.8927, -0.3429, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.7593, -0.2012, -3.2100],
                  [1.5000, 0.0903, -3.0909],
                  [2.2037, 0.3673, -2.8958],
                  [2.8532, 0.6228, -2.6293],
                  [3.4324, 0.8508, -2.2981],
                  [3.9271, 1.0455, -1.9103],
                  [4.3250, 1.2021, -1.4755],
                  [4.6165, 1.3168, -1.0043],
                  [4.7943, 1.3868, -0.5084],
                  [4.8541, 1.4103, 0],
                  [4.7943, 1.3868, 0.5084],
                  [4.6165, 1.3168, 1.0043],
                  [4.3250, 1.2021, 1.4755],
                  [3.9271, 1.0455, 1.9103],
                  [3.4324, 0.8508, 2.2981],
                  [2.8532, 0.6228, 2.6293],
                  [2.2037, 0.3673, 2.8958],
                  [1.5000, 0.0903, 3.0909],
                  [0.7593, -0.2012, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.5517, -0.0887, -3.2100],
                  [1.0898, 0.3125, -3.0909],
                  [1.6011, 0.6937, -2.8958],
                  [2.0729, 1.0455, -2.6293],
                  [2.4938, 1.3592, -2.2981],
                  [2.8532, 1.6272, -1.9103],
                  [3.1423, 1.8427, -1.4755],
                  [3.3541, 2.0006, -1.0043],
                  [3.4833, 2.0969, -0.5084],
                  [3.5267, 2.1293, 0],
                  [3.4833, 2.0969, 0.5084],
                  [3.3541, 2.0006, 1.0043],
                  [3.1423, 1.8427, 1.4755],
                  [2.8532, 1.6272, 1.9103],
                  [2.4938, 1.3592, 2.2981],
                  [2.0729, 1.0455, 2.6293],
                  [1.6011, 0.6937, 2.8958],
                  [1.0898, 0.3125, 3.0909],
                  [0.5517, -0.0887, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.2900, -0.0165, -3.2100],
                  [0.5729, 0.4552, -3.0909],
                  [0.8417, 0.9033, -2.8958],
                  [1.0898, 1.3168, -2.6293],
                  [1.3110, 1.6856, -2.2981],
                  [1.5000, 2.0006, -1.9103],
                  [1.6520, 2.2540, -1.4755],
                  [1.7634, 2.4397, -1.0043],
                  [1.8313, 2.5529, -0.5084],
                  [1.8541, 2.5909, 0],
                  [1.8313, 2.5529, 0.5084],
                  [1.7634, 2.4397, 1.0043],
                  [1.6520, 2.2540, 1.4755],
                  [1.5000, 2.0006, 1.9103],
                  [1.3110, 1.6856, 2.2981],
                  [1.0898, 1.3168, 2.6293],
                  [0.8417, 0.9033, 2.8958],
                  [0.5729, 0.4552, 3.0909],
                  [0.2900, -0.0165, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [0.0000, 0.0084, -3.2100],
                  [0.0000, 0.5043, -3.0909],
                  [0.0000, 0.9755, -2.8958],
                  [0.0000, 1.4103, -2.6293],
                  [0.0000, 1.7981, -2.2981],
                  [0.0000, 2.1293, -1.9103],
                  [0.0000, 2.3958, -1.4755],
                  [0.0000, 2.5909, -1.0043],
                  [0.0000, 2.7100, -0.5084],
                  [0.0000, 2.7500, 0],
                  [0.0000, 2.7100, 0.5084],
                  [0.0000, 2.5909, 1.0043],
                  [0.0000, 2.3958, 1.4755],
                  [0.0000, 2.1293, 1.9103],
                  [0.0000, 1.7981, 2.2981],
                  [0.0000, 1.4103, 2.6293],
                  [0.0000, 0.9755, 2.8958],
                  [0.0000, 0.5043, 3.0909],
                  [0.0000, 0.0084, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500],
                  [0, -0.5000, -3.2500],
                  [-0.2900, -0.0165, -3.2100],
                  [-0.5729, 0.4552, -3.0909],
                  [-0.8417, 0.9033, -2.8958],
                  [-1.0898, 1.3168, -2.6293],
                  [-1.3110, 1.6856, -2.2981],
                  [-1.5000, 2.0006, -1.9103],
                  [-1.6520, 2.2540, -1.4755],
                  [-1.7634, 2.4397, -1.0043],
                  [-1.8313, 2.5529, -0.5084],
                  [-1.8541, 2.5909, 0],
                  [-1.8313, 2.5529, 0.5084],
                  [-1.7634, 2.4397, 1.0043],
                  [-0.9386, -0.5000, 3.2100],
                  [0, -0.5000, 3.2500]])
    print("calibrate_magnetometer:\n{}".format(calibrate_magnetometer(a)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the traceback that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../bin/calculateCalibration.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "../bin/calculateCalibration.py", line 7, in main
    print(str(raw_data.calculate_calibration()))
  File "C:\Users\magnetfeld-kabel\util\bin\magnetic.py", line 297, in calculate_calibration
    calibrated_u, calibrated_c = calibrate_magnetometer(calibration_data)
  File "C:\Users\magnetfeld-kabel\util\bin\magnetic.py", line 173, in calibrate_magnetometer
    D = np.triu(qr(D.T)[1])  # avoids to compute the svd of a large matrix
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_qr.py", line 171, in qr
    overwrite_a=1)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_qr.py", line 21, in safecall
    ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.9 GiB for an array with shape (46150, 46150) and data type float64
```

Comment: well, the matrix is not so large; to me it seems that you are implementing a lot of stuff that has been implemented in numpy or scipy

Comment: How much memory does the Python code use and what exactly is your memory error?

Comment: @ThomasHilger I tried to use as many numpy/scipy algorithms as possible (e.g., the Cholesky factorization). Can you please point out what else I can use?

Comment: @André monitoring the process in Task-Manager, it uses 25Gbyte of RAM. I add the error to the question above.

Comment: Adding the traceback pushed the body size of the post over the limit, so I shortened the array in the python code.

Comment: Matlab’s `qr` with one output is giving only R. In the Python code it looks like you’re computing both Q and R and then throwing away Q. You probably want `mode=‘r’` for `qr` In Python.

Comment: @bg2b that works, and as a bonus, it speeds up the calculation a lot, too!

Comment: What about `usolve` and `utsolve`. First of all, transposing an array or swapping an axis should be approximately free in numpy; if i am not mistaken, the elements are stored flat anyway and transposing just interchanges the strives; so what is the reason for not using `numpy.linalg.solve`? If it is what you are solving there, take it; very smart people with a lot of knowledge in programming AND numerics of linear equations have worked on this kind of functions; I believe I could never come up with something better myself; in case you are calculating something else there, please explain what

Comment: @ThomasHilger right, I will check that out. There are solvers in matlab, too, and the authors of the calibration code for matlab could have used it if it was a drop-in replacement for usolv and utsolve - with that reasoning I ported those two functions.